# Python insert operation on list

Tags: python, list

I am newbie to Python and I have a doubt regarding insert operation on the list.

Example 1:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e']
mylist.insert(len(mylist),'f')
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Example 2:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e']
mylist.insert(10,'f')
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

In second example why it still inserts 'f' element in the list even if I am giving index 10 to insert method?

Comment: What do you expect the other indexes to contain if it did put `'f'` in the 10th index?

Comment: @Volatility a not unreasonable assumption would be an error of some sort

Comment: I was expecting error. Why it's working that way and not giving any error.

Comment: @vivekratnaparkhi If you really thing it is wrong, submit a Python Enhancement Proposal. Note: There are no more changes, ever, to existing interfaces in the Python 2.x family.

Answer (score 4):

The `list.insert` function will insert before the specified index. Since the `list` is not that long anyways in your example, it goes on the end. Why not just use `list.append` if you want to put stuff on the end anyways.

```
x = ['a']
x.append('b')
print x
```

Output is

```
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: @vivekratnaparkhi : This behaviour is clearly stated in the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Quoting - `a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).`

Comment: @vivekratnaparkhi If you want the philisophical answer, read up on the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: The OP is not talking about using insert to add to the end of a list *per se*... he expected that trying to insert at a position way past the end of the list might raise an error (probably `IndexError`).  i.e, why should `a.insert(len(a), x)` be equivalent to `a.insert(len(a)+1000000000, x)`.  That, I'm guessing, is where the doubt still lies.

Answer (score 2):

The concept here is "insert before the element with this index". To be able to insert at the end, you have to allow the invalid off-the-end index. Since there are no well-defined "off-the-end iterators" or anything in Python, it makes more sense to just allow all indices than to allow one invalid one, but no others.